# Reading an image VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image

Is it possible to **read a text on an image**?
Why yes and why not?
My client wants me to make this but I think it's impossible, if not impossible then it'll be very hard to make.. I was trying to explain it to him but it seems like he really wants to push it. 
:/

EDIT: I don't understand why you downvoted this I was just asking a yes or no question here. :)) but well it's ok I want to hear what do you guys think if this is possible in vb.net

Comment: In an image everything are pixels; nothing which can be considered "text". If these pixels happen to form letters, it wouldn't really matter, you would have to perform the image analysis anyway. Most likely, the reason why you got a -1 (it wasn't me) was because you used "reading" when talking about an image what seems to indicate a profound lack of understanding of the programming basics (SO for knowledgeable programmers, asking relevant questions, etc.). If you have an adequate knowledge, you should reword your question such that it is reflected there; also you should show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) to get the images, then perform OCR on them with for ex. [Tersseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). 
Problem is where should that text be used? In the PDF? If yes it might be possible to include a textfield above the image with the text in the PDF, using PDFSharp too.

Comment: Actually it's just a feature to the app. We have this some kind of "reports" that are in a pdf format, which sometimes contains images and he wants me to read what's inside (this is really freaking me out), sometimes the image is handwritten but sometimes it's computerized

Comment: Maybe that helps you getting started, not impossible at all just work ;)

Comment: Hmm. I have one last question. Using PDFsharp, does it literally "extract" the image? I mean, will it create a different file, for example test.jpeg or will it be extracted to a different pdf file with only the test.jpeg inside it?

Comment: nevermind, got it. This is the link I was working on, it is on C# though. I'll just translate it to VB and post the codes :) `http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx`